# were witches in northern England more common?

Tags: folklore

Were witches in northern England more common than in other parts of the U.K. I read about Pendle Hill and it seems so .

Comment: [The idea that there were people who self-idetified as witches during the Middle Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch-cult_hypothesis) is not given much credence any more.

Comment: [Susanna Clark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonathan_Strange_%26_Mr_Norrell#Volume_I:_Mr_Norrell) definitely seems to suggest this, but Shakespeare wrote about that "great magician, damned [Glendower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen_Glendower_(Shakespeare_character))" who was a Welshman.

Comment: The words "magician" and "witch" have very different etymologies in English. Around the time of Shakespeare, a magician would be someone practicing [legerdemain](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=legerdemain), whereas "witch" would have meant to Shakespeare _a woman supposed to have dealings with the devil or evil spirits and to be able by their cooperation to perform supernatural acts_.

Comment: Lancashire did have a reputation for having many witches. Some historians have argued this is because people there could pose as witches for profit (witches could act like a kind of herbalist healer).